# Django import from csv(update_or_create)

Tags: python, django, csv, django-models, django-orm

my program loads data from csv (customoer, item, total), here is my data model:

```
from django.db import models


class Member(models.Model):
    customer = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    item = models.JSONField(max_length=50)
    total = models.IntegerField()

def __str__(self):
    return self.customer
```

My view:

```
def upload(request):
    template = 'upload.html'

    promt = {
        'member': 'Member of CSV should be customer, item, total'
    }

    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, template, promt)

    csv_file = request.FILES['file']

    if not csv_file.name.endswith('.csv'):
        messages.error(request, 'This is not a csv file')

    data_set = csv_file.read().decode('UTF-8')
    io_string = io.StringIO(data_set)
    next(io_string)
    for column in csv.reader(io_string, delimiter=','):
        _, created = Member.objects.update_or_create(
            customer=column[0],
            item=column[1],
            total=column[2]
        )
    context = {}
    return render(request, template, context)
```

In general, the download works, but instead of updating the user data, a new object is created with the same customer, how can I make it so that a new customer is not created, but only the total and item are updated in it?

Example CSV data:

```
customer,item,total
bellwether,Cavorit,6126
resplendent,Saphire,8502
bellwether,Ruby,342
```

Instead of not creating two or more objects with the bellwether customer, there was only one object with customer bellwether an item ("Kavorit", "Ruby"), total (6468).
Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that when you pass all 3 fields in and django looks up the database, if there is a query that matches all 3 fields at the same time, obviously if one of them is different then the existing one, it does not match and creates a new one. The documentation says [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create)

> The update_or_create method tries to fetch an object from database
> based on the given kwargs. If a match is found, it updates the fields
> passed in the defaults dictionary.

So try this:

```
 _, created = Member.objects.update_or_create(
            customer=column[0]
            defaults={ "item":column[1], "total":column[2] }
        )
```